# how can you use playerprefs to save an array in javascript on unity

Tags: unity, javascript

As I stated I can't find a working answer anywhere else. I have a game where you are to draw out your own weapon and I'm storing that information in an array. How?

Answer (score 2):

You would first need to serialize your array into a string.  One way to do this, is to create a tokenizable string representation of your array data.

For example:

```
string data = "";

for (int n = 0; n < Array.GetLength(0); n++) {
    data += Array[n].ToString();
    if(n != Array.GetLength(0) - 1)
        data += ",";
}

PlayerPrefs.SetString("ArrayData", data);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Then loading this back into the array would look something like this:

```
string data = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ArrayData");
string[] tokens = data.Split(',');

Array = new Array[tokens.GetLength(0)];
for (int n = 0; n < tokens.GetLength(0); n++) {
    Array[n] = tokens[n];    //Cast to var type here
}
```

Comment: Is there no `join` operator or method?

Comment: It isn't working at all! I'm getting errors on inserting semicolons

Comment: What is the error.

Comment: On the line that says. string[] tokens = data.Split(','); the console displays " ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end." On colomn 15 and 17